# error 10064 mysql 4200 while trying to create table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE DIAMOND( 
RAPNETSELLERCODE  VARCHAR(30) , 
SHAPE  VARCHAR(15) , 
WEIGHT INT(5) , 
    COLOR VARCHAR(3) ,
    CLARITY VARCHAR(6) ,
    CUTGRADE VARCHAR(10),
    POLISH VARCHAR(13),
SYMMENTRY VARCHAR(10),
FLUORESCE VARCHAR(10),
MEASUREMENTS INT(100),
MEASLENGTH INT(30),
MEASWIDTH INT(30),
MEASDEPTH INT(30),
RATIO INT(12),
LAB VARCHAR(10),
ID INT(15),
STOCK# VARCHAR(14),
    RAPNETPRICE INT(15), 
    RAPNETDISCOUNTPRICE INT(15),
RAPTOTALPRICE INT(16),
DEPTH %  INT(12),
TABLE %  INT(10),
GIRDLE VARCHAR(10),
CULET  VARCHAR(10),
CERTIFICATEURL VARCHAR(300),
RAPNETLOT # INT(38);


ERROR:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
CREATE TABLE DIAMOND(
    RAPNETSELLERCODE  VARCHAR(30) ,
    SHAPE  VARCHAR(15) ,' at line 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please ready the FAQ on how to properly write your question.  In particular, please read how to `format your code`, as it makes reading things much easier.  Also, be sure to actually ask a question!

Comment: Please read the error message. It clearly complaints about a closing parenthesis that's not in the code you've shared.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently there is more to the query than what you are showing us.  Seems like you have something like

```
CREATE TABLE PLATINUM (
    /* fields */
)
CREATE TABLE DIAMOND (
```

You need a semicolon after the `)` before `CREATE TABLE DIAMOND`.

You have other errors in this `CREATE TABLE` statement as well.

```
STOCK # -- invalid syntax
`STOCK #` -- desired syntax
```

Same is true of `DEPTH %`, `TABLE %`, and `RAPNETLOT #`

Finally, you are missing the closing paren for the entire `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Several things I can see: you have a `%` symbol in 2 lines of code, you have a `#` symbol in 2 lines of code, you have DEPTH and TABLE as column names although they are keywords, and you never closed your parenthesis inside the semicolon.  At least one of these things is causing the error message.  Start with the `)` you are missing.